# Would 売り手 be the right word for a store clerk? What about cashier?

Tags: translation, word-choice

売り手 means seller or vendor. Could it also be used in reference to the cashier, or perhaps a store clerk? Or would that not be correct because (Example: they are just in charge of collecting the money for the book that is being sold at the store?)

> あの売り手にだまされました。 I was cheated by that vendor.
>
> その家の売り手は、近所の人が本当にひどいやつなので、家を手放すことにしたんだと私に話した。
>
> The guy selling that house told me he’s selling it because his
>   neighbor is a real jerk.

Comment: Store clerk and cashier might not have exactly the same meaning. It might help if you update the title of your question. For store clerk, ten'in seems to be the best fit; it's the one I've seen and heard most often used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you don't refer to a person in charge of cashier as 売り手 but 会計の人, レジの人 or 売り子 depending on what and how they sell.